# What is the best practice querying related table with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.0

I have `Asp.Net Core 2` `Web Api` application, I'm using `Ef Core 2` with `Repository / Unit of Work` pattern. I have to query user posts from `Database`, the posts entity looks like this:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // This is User Id from AspNetUsers
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string PostContent { get; set; }
}
```

In my repository I have query:

```
public class FeedRepository : BaseRepository, IFeedRepository, IDisposable
{
    public FeedRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Post> GetPosts(string currentUserId, IEnumerable<string> followingUserIds)
    {
        // Which returns list of Post entities
        return Db.Posts.Where(p => p.AuthorId == currentUserId || followingUserIds.Contains(p.AuthorId));
    }
    ...
}
```

So my point is that I want to return response like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "authorId": "asdasd-fg4543-fgfvc-45345-sdfsf",
        "authorFullName": "Jane Doe",
        "postContent": "Test Post by Jane Doe.."
    }
]
```

What is the best practice to `Join` or somehow get full name of author and put in same entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add `Author` property into `Post`

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // This is User Id from AspNetUsers
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    public User Author { get; set; }

    public string PostContent { get; set; }
}
```

That expresses that `Post` can not be created without `User`.

Use `Include` to retrieve navigation property value via `EF`

```
public IEnumerable<Post> GetPosts(string currentUserId, IEnumerable<string> followingUserIds)
{
    return Db.Posts.Include(it => it.Author).Where(p => p.AuthorId == currentUserId || followingUserIds.Contains(p.AuthorId));
}
```